# html.ActionLink using wrong route

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes

I have set up the following routes so that I can use duplicate controller names (in different namespaces). This works fine but when I use html.actionlink from any controller it always includes the “CRUD” subfolder to the link.

```
var route1 = routes.MapRoute(
    "CRUD",
    "CRUD/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
route1.DataTokens["Namespaces"] = new string[] { "College.Controllers.CRUD" };
route1.DataTokens["UseNamespaceFallback"] = false;

var route2 = routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    namespaces: new[] { "College.Controllers" }
);

route2.DataTokens["Namespaces"] = new string[] { "College.Controllers" };
route2.DataTokens["UseNamespaceFallback"] = false;
```

So an html.actionlink in http://localhost/students/index looks like this
http://localhost/CRUD/students/Edit/1

What I want is this 
http://localhost/students/Edit/1

I know I could fix this by specifying the route in the actionlink but I don’t want to do this because I want to re-scaffold in future and my changes would be overwritten.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that your 2 routes are ambiguous when building the URL. There are basically 3 ways to fix this:

1. Add another route value to match that is not part of the URL.
2. Use `RouteLink` to specify the route by name (along with the other route value criteria to make it match).
3. Create a custom route to handle "constraining" it to a specific namespace or make a custom route constraint.

Since you explicitly stated the second option is unacceptable, here is an example of the first:

```
var route1 = routes.MapRoute(
               "CRUD",
               "CRUD/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
               new { crud = "crud", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }

           );
    route1.DataTokens["Namespaces"] = new string[] { "College.Controllers.CRUD" };
    route1.DataTokens["UseNamespaceFallback"] = false;

var route2 = routes.MapRoute(
               "Default",
               "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
               new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }

           );
    route1.DataTokens["Namespaces"] = new string[] { "College.Controllers" };
    route1.DataTokens["UseNamespaceFallback"] = false;
```

Now when you call `@Html.ActionLink("Students", "Index", "Students", new { crud = (string)null }, null)` it will not match the `CRUD` route, it will match the `Default` route.

To make it match the `CRUD` route, you have to explicitly add the route value to the ActionLink: `@Html.ActionLink("Students", "Index", "Students", new { crud = "crud" }, null)` or leave it out entirely: `@Html.ActionLink("Students", "Index", "Students")`

### Constraining the Route

Here is an example of the 3rd option.

Unfortunately, we can't use a regular route constraint because Microsoft decided not to make the `RequestContext` object available in the `IRouteConstraint` interface. This means the namespace information about what controller the request is bound for is not available. So, we need to drop to a lower level and make a custom `RouteBase` class that implements the decorator pattern to wrap our existing `Route` class configuration.

This class simply checks to see if the namespace from the request matches a specific namespace before generating the URL.

```
public class NamespaceConstrainedRoute : RouteBase
{
    private readonly string namespaceToMatch;
    private readonly RouteBase innerRoute;

    public NamespaceConstrainedRoute(string namespaceToMatch, RouteBase innerRoute)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(namespaceToMatch))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("namespaceToMatch");
        if (innerRoute == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("innerRoute");
        this.namespaceToMatch = namespaceToMatch;
        this.innerRoute = innerRoute;
    }

    public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        return innerRoute.GetRouteData(httpContext);
    }

    public override VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
    {
        object namespaces;
        if (requestContext.RouteData.DataTokens.TryGetValue("Namespaces", out namespaces)
            && namespaces is IList<string>
            && ((IList<string>)namespaces).Contains(namespaceToMatch))
        {
            return innerRoute.GetVirtualPath(requestContext, values);
        }

        // null indicates to try to match the next route in the route table
        return null;
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
var route1 = new Route(
        url: "CRUD/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new RouteValueDictionary(new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }),
        routeHandler: new MvcRouteHandler()
    )
{
    DataTokens = new RouteValueDictionary
    {
        { "Namespaces",  new string[] { "College.Controllers.CRUD" }},
        { "UseNamespaceFallback", false }
    }
};

var route2 = new Route(
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }),
        routeHandler: new MvcRouteHandler()
    )
{
    DataTokens = new RouteValueDictionary
    {
        { "Namespaces",  new string[] { "College.Controllers" }},
        { "UseNamespaceFallback", false }
    }
};

routes.Add(
    name: "CRUD",
    item: new NamespaceConstrainedRoute(
        namespaceToMatch: "College.Controllers.CRUD", 
        innerRoute: route1));

routes.Add(
    name: "Default",
    item: new NamespaceConstrainedRoute(
        namespaceToMatch: "College.Controllers",
        innerRoute: route2));
```

From this point, you could build your own `MapRoute` extension methods if you so choose to make the above configuration look cleaner.

Comment: I tried the route you suggested for the first solution but the links created by the action link still have the "CRUD" subfolder in them. This is the action link that appear in the views when they are scaffolded: @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.StudentId }) which produces the following link: http://localhost/CRUD/students/Edit/1

Comment: I updated the answer with an example that works for the first option (my mistake), but it is no longer quite so elegant. If you ask me, using `RouteLink` and naming the route is a better option.